# Angular option to vet symbols in a template

Tags: angular, symbols, lint

As an Angular/TypeScript/VSCode user, I use great tools such as tslint, Wallaby.js, markdownlint, sasslint, and others to provide a robust safety net to help me try to avoid introducing code problems, whether they be subtle or shoot-yourself-in-the-foot type. But there is one glaring omission to this ecosystem... or is there? I am hoping it is simply my ignorance and someone will be able to jump in and say, "Of course you can do that, just install x!"

What I find lacking is an ability to vet the symbols used in an Angular template. Neither the compiler or any linter I have found can check, for example, from this Angular template fragment...

```
<click-outside (clickOutside)="closeDropdown()">{{ scenario }}
  <dropdown [attr.visible]="active">
    <checkbox
      *ngFor="let project of projectsArray()"
      [checked]="project.checked"
      [attr.title]="project.name"
      (change)="projectChecked($event.detail, project)"
    </checkbox>
  </dropdown>
</click-outside>
```

... whether any of the properties (active, scenario) or functions (closeDropdown, projectsArray, projectChecked) are defined. 
They should all be statically defined so that should be vettable at compile time.

Sure, much of the time, such an omission will be immediately evident when you actually run your code. But that's neither reliable nor scalable.

And a smaller percentage of the time your suite of tests would catch it, but it is notoriously challenging to do the "last mile" of unit tests that actually vet what's rendered in the browser, so again not a reliable mechanism.

*The question:* is there something to do such symbol vetting? Could be in any of these forms, or something else:

1. Angular configuration option
2. standalone command-line utility (linux)
3. IDE plugin (VSCode)

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/language-service

Comment: Thank you, @joyBlanks! That does indeed satisfy point 3, the VSCode plugin, and it will be very useful! But that immediately made me realize that I also need a way to vet my entire (rather large) code-base other than manually opening each file in VSCode. So still looking for a command-line approach, too.

Comment: I think ng lint should cover that you should have codelyzer in angular projects

Comment: Hmm... any thoughts on where the codelyzer rules are explained beyond just their names...?

Comment: if you run ng lint it should throw errors about the templates and ts files